# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please what is wrong with this code.I have removed all white spaces. I have checked for semi colons in the code. I still have the same error.

I read before that it could happen because of white empty spaces but I don't see any empty white spaces in my code below. I have edited the question.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, Text, Card } from 'react-native-elements';

class DetailsScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Details',
  };
  render() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const matches = JSON.parse(navigation.getParam('matches', 'No matches found'));
  console.log(matches)

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Card style={styles.container}>
        {
          matches.map((item, key) => (
            <View key={key} style={styles.subContainer}>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>{item.group}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>{item.team1.name}</Text>

             <Text>{item.team2.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>{item.date}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
            <Text style={styles.baseText}>{item.score1}</Text>

            <Text>{item.score2}</Text>
            </View>
              if(item.goals1.length > 0) {
                item.goals1.map((item2, key2) => (
                  <View key={key2}><Text style={styles.baseText}>{item2.name} {item2.minute}</Text></View>
                ))
              }
              if(item.goals2.length > 0) {
                item.goals2.map((item3, key3) => (
                  <View key={key3}><Text style={styles.baseText}>{item3.name} {item3.minute}</Text></View>
                ))
              }</View>
          ))
        }
      </Card>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20
  },
  subContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#CCCCCC'
  },
  baseText:{
    fontFamily:'Cochin',
  fontSize:14,
  fontWeight:'bold'}
})
export default DetailsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove h2, h3, h3 from Text components since it has no props (not fatal, but useless) and you dont need `()` here either ({item2.minute}) which actually breaks the code

i suggest also checking out what props and methods Text component have here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html

hope this helps

Comment: check the question again.I have edited it.still got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Agree with wijuwiju's answer also do not nest other elements including `<Text>` inside a `<Text>` component. It will mostly create problems even if now on one platform you don't see any problems.